# Guideline for dynamic styling in lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components

There are two ways for dynamic styling in LWC -

1. CSS class binding like `<div class={styleClass}>` with getter.
2. Handle `classList` in the target element with `querySelector()`.

   Is there any guideline or best practice for which to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getter method has the advantage of remembering the state when a component is hidden/shown (e.g. via if:true or if:false), while the DOM-manipulation method can't. On the other hand, using DOM-manipulation likely has better performance characteristics in larger components. I'm not sure there's a solid recommendation either way, but I would suggest that you choose one method and use it consistently.

Comment: I would add that when you use the DOM manipulation method, you're limited to static styles that have been pre-defined in CSS.  If you want to handle use cases like "the background color should be configurable in Lightning App Builder", I think you have to use inline CSS.

Comment: @MatthewSouther That's a good point. I had a feeling I was missing something.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox and Matthew!! Makes sense.